# Work-around for aliasing the URL of a private site

Tags: sharepoint-online, url, redirect

Version: Office 365 SharePoint Online

Plan: Education

We recently started up a new *site collection* which we have dedicated to one site which acts as a central site for our company. I realise that **aliasing** a URL for a public site is possible, and not for a private site. Still I would love to know if anyone has figured out a work-around (such as a crafty way of using a **CNAME**, or **Apache2** redirect rule, or even somehow using term sets).

The end goal is that I would like to find some way of users going to *sub1.domain.com* and being redirected to *company.sharepoint.com/sites/abc123* while the URL remains unchanged.

Comment: Is your DNS managed in O365 or in your domain name registrar?

Comment: @AzizKabyshev It's managed by external name servers, not O365.

Answer (score 2):

Due to `*.sharepoint.com` SSL certificate that's used for all *non-public* SharePoint Online sites it's **not possible** to map your custom hostname like `sp.company.com`. Office 365 currently doesn't allow using custom SSL certs for web resources, nor creating non-HTTPS sites.

Any DNS-level manipulations will lead to 'Invalid certificate' errors, and practically make SP unusable.

I ended up setting simple Moved Permanently redirect for a subdomain in web hosting where our `www` is located. But that's just a handy trick for users' convenience.

Comment: Thank you, Aziz, that makes sense. I've tried to set up an Apache redirect and messed around with DNS but nothing works and now I see why. But I was thinking about setting up an alias in Rackspace just this morning, as per your suggestion. Theoretically, it should work. Wish me luck! :)

Comment: Update: Rackspace only aliases to other rackspace cloud sites. But I am currently looking into domain forwarding through GoDaddy - I will post another update soon.

Comment: @OnSys Hi there. Did you manage to set it up?

Comment: Not yet, sorry. I'll have more time to look into this next week so will post the good/bad news then.

Comment: @OnSys This task would have to be handled by the *web server* located at `sub1.domain.com`. (Since it is an HTTP redirect, it cannot be handled by DNS.) If you have control of the web server at `domain.com`, you should be able to set up a permanent redirect there. If not, what prevents it?